# How does google crawl pages that have a numbered or next or previous buttons

Tags: search, google-search, web-crawler

I have a search page that contains paged results. How does Google know to go to the next page so it can crawl all the content and not just the 1st page?

Answer (score 1):

Google actually recommends using rel="next" and rel="prev" for paginated pages.

Basically you'll insert two additional tags in the head of the document (except on the first and last page):

```
<head>
    …
    <link rel="prev" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=1" />
    <link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=3" />
    …
</head>
```

More Info can be found in their blog: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ch/2012/03/video-about-pagination-with-relnext-and.html

Even if you don't do this, google usually does a pretty good job indexing paged results. But it doesn't hurt to help them.